# Is it possible to use the Model Factories with a wrapper service in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

The Model Factory functionality available in Laravel 5.2 provide for some very convenient methods, especially during testing.

For example:

```
factory(User::class)->create();
```

Is it possible to utilise some existing functionality to get something similar for any wrapper services that might be creating those eloquent instances?

For instance, I have a `UserService` class that does business logic checks before touching the model. Functionality that doesn't belong within the model, nor does it belong in a controller.

For example:

```
// Controller
//
Route('/bla/', function(UserService $userService) {
    $user = $userService->create(request()->all());

    return view('blabla.view');
});

// User Service
// 
function create($input) 
{
    // .. do some business logic stuff here .. 
    // .. then some more over here
    // .. finally if some condition is met, then create a user
    $user = User::create($filteredInput);

    return $user;
}

// User Model 
// Bog standard user model
```

Now I don't want to introduce the faker library into the user service itself. Ideally I want to pass in the defined model factory for the class in through the service, which in turn passes it down and through into the model.

Comment: Why don't you use the build in phpunit testing suite?

Comment: Thanks, but I am looking for a way to leverage factories for non-models

Comment: If your object has a constructor and you use the factory()->make() function, I don't see why it shouldn't work